# A question in Ring theory

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

R be a commutative ring with unity and it has exactly one maximal ideal. Then prove that the equation  $x^2 =x$  has exactly two solutions.

Show me the right way to solbe this one.

Comment: Saying *please* would be more polite; and explaining what you'd tried or thought about yourself tends to make people more willing to help.

Answer (score 2):

Let $\mathfrak{m}$ be the unique maximal ideal of $R$. If $x^2=x$, then $0=x^2-x=x(x-1)$. If $x\in\mathfrak{m}$, then $1-x\in R^\times$ since $x\in\mathcal{J}(R)=\mathfrak{m}$, hence not a zero-divisor. If $x\notin\mathfrak{m}$, then $x\in R^\times$, hence not a zero-divisor. So $x=0,1$ are the only solutions.